# Qt Quick: Rectangle not displaying

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am creating a basic login form, however the rectangle is not displaying. Please bear with with me!

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 600

    LoginForm {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        //height: 300
        //width: 300
    }

}
```

LoginForm.ui.qml:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Item {

    Rectangle {
        color: "#E8E8E8"
        radius: 5
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        anchors.fill: parent
        width: childrenRect.width
        height: childrenRect.height

        GridLayout {
            id: "grid_layout"
            flow: GridLayout.TopToBottom
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.topMargin: 12
            anchors.bottomMargin: 12
            anchors.leftMargin: 12
            anchors.rightMargin: 12

            Text {
                id: "log_in_label"
                text: "Log In"
                font.pointSize: 15;
            }

            Text {
                id: "username_label"
                text: "Username:"
                font.pointSize: 8
            }

            TextField {
                id: "username_input"
                Layout.columnSpan: 2
                font.pointSize: 8
            }

            Text {
                id: "password_label"
                text: "Password:"
                font.pointSize: 8
            }

            TextField {
                id: "password_input"
                Layout.columnSpan: 2
                font.pointSize: 8
            }

            Button {
                text: "Sign in"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am completely new to Qt Quick and I do not understand why this does not work, however when I uncomment "height: 300" and "width: 300" the thing magically works. Why is this and how should I overcome this as I do not wish to position them manually I would much rather use ratios and layouts.

Comment: I don't have the time to go through it in detail. On thing that popped into my eye: Never specify the size through two conflicting systems. Either use the resizing from anchors, or from layouts or from width or height. `anchors.fill: parent` and `width: x` in the same item are bad.

Comment: On the other hand: `anchors.centerIn` does not resize the item. So the root `Item` in your `LoginForm.ui.qml` has no size. No the `Rectangle` is resized to it, since it is filling it.

Comment: Where is `childrenRect` specified? As I see you have nowhere specified `width` and `height` of the item.

Comment: @naide: childrenRect is a property, specified in `QQuickItem`

Comment: @derM Oh, that's true, I forgot that. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you don't see anything is this:

In your `LoginForm.ui.qml` you have an `Item` which is filled by a `Rectangle`

```
Item { // This Item has no size unless you specify it, when instantiating it (uncomment width and height)

    Rectangle {
        color: "#E8E8E8"
        radius: 5
        anchors.centerIn: parent 
        anchors.fill: parent // This will fill the Item. As long as you don't specify a size, it will be invisibile.
        width: childrenRect.width // This conflicts with the anchors. It will be ignored.
        height: childrenRect.height // This conflicts with the anchors. It will be ignored.

        [...]
    }
}
```

What you could do is set the `implicitWidth/Height` of the `Item` to the size it should have, when you do not externally specify a size.

```
Item {
    implicitHeight: // calculate the size it should have when the size is not changed
    implicitWidth: // here as well.

    Rectangle {
        color: "#E8E8E8"
        radius: 5
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    GridLayout {
        anchors {
            fill: parent
            leftMargin: 12
            [...]
        }
        [...]

        Button {
            text: "Sign in"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how would you explain that the button and input fields are visible?
Not sure if implicitHeight would do anything for what I want to achieve. I want the rectangle to be around the form itself, with 12px margin which is specified in the GridLayout. I want the rectangle's size to adjust so I am trying not to use bare pixels (thus if anyone has idea how to replace the manual margin with a ratio one I'm open to suggestions).

Comment: It does explain that, since you don't resize the `Button` nor the `InputField` in relation to their parents. So their `implicitWidth` and `implictHeight` are used.

Comment: If you don't want to need to set a size of the `LoginForm` where you instantiate it, you should set the `implicitWidth/Height` of it inside the `LoginForm.ui.qml`. I can't tell you what the right size for that is. That depends on the natural size of the content.

Comment: If I specify implicitHeight/Width I still use pixels instead of ratios. I want the rectangle to automatically set to a size to fit the content *just enough* (+margins).

Comment: Then set the implicitHeight/Width to some fancy formula that calculates exactly that size, you want to have. You can use the childrenRect sizes, you can use your knowledge about the content, their implicit or explicit sizes and positions to do calculate that. What you can't do, is having all the children depending their size on the parent, while the parent's size is depending on their children at the same time. That means, either you resize the children in relation to their parent, or the parent in relation to the (implizit) size of the children.

Comment: Thank you! This becomes much more clearer! I will later let you know how it goes!

Comment: I solved the problem, by deleting the part where the GridLayout resize to fill the Rectangle (which resizes to fit GridLayout - loop). However, the thing that surprises me is that in QtQuick the input fields would be visible even if the parent (rectangle) was not because it had size x: 0, y: 0. This would not have place in QtWidgets. There, if the parent has size 0 by 0, then by default, all of its children have size 0 by 0 and thus are not visible. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the outer Item {  } in LoginForm.ui.qml

Comment: Hmmm, could you explain why this works? Also, how would I go about making the rectangle the size *just enough* to fit the content (+margins)?

Comment: The default value for width/height is 0. You didn’t set another value.
Furthermore, the outer empty item is not needed since a Rectangle is an Item itself.
If you want it to follow the size of the content, refer to childrenRect, as you’ve done already with the GridLayout.